# (3,1): The internal 'module' syntax is deprecated, use the 'namespace' keyword instead

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have built an react app using create-react-app in TypeScript and Yarn workspaces, and when I starting  the server using `yarn start` I get this error:

```
Failed to compile.

../packages/web/src/App.tsx
(3,1): The internal 'module' syntax is deprecated, use the 'namespace' keyword instead.
```

Where can be the problem?

**UPDATE:** It is important to note that I also used [this YARN workspace](https://github.com/benawad/typescript-yarn-workspace-example) and there it was used in TypeScript version 2.9.1, whereas I installed the current version (3+) And from there the fault was probably due to a collision between the code base and changes between the TS versions.

Comment: That's the point
 I haven't wrote anything. I have just built a simple app using create-react-app cli.

Comment: 'create-react-app in TypeScript' - create-react-app doesn't create App.tsx. It's purely JS. There are third-party CRA templates that use TS, and the problem is likely specific to some template you used. Questions should contain all necessary information to replicate the problem on SO. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

"typescript": "^3.1.1" in packages/server/package.json seems to have worked